# Django. Не отображаются локальные файлы

Tags: django

Django, библиотека со списком книг, изображения были указаны ссылками и отображались. Необходимо загрузить изображения в базу данных и подгружать уже из нее. И на этом этапе изображения выводиться перестали, выводится только альтернативный текст. Разместил в папке медиа статический файл для книг без обложен, он тоже не отображается в Джанго. Но если просмотреть код элемента, скопировать ссылку и вставить во вкладку рядом, изображение выводится. Изображения базы данных не выводятся, но они и на ПК не открываются, какая то доп защита.

```
cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='book_covers/', null=True, blank=True)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Не выводится ни в первом ни во втором случае

```
DEFAULT_IMAGE_PATH = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'media', 'default_image.jpg')

{% if book.cover_image %}
                <img src="{{ book.cover_image.url }}" alt="{{ book.title }}" class="card-img-top img-fluid"
                     style="width: 150px; height: 200px;">
                {% else %}
                <img src="{{ default_image }}" alt="Стандартное изображение" class="card-img-top img-fluid"
                     style="width: 150px; height: 200px;">
                {% endif %}
```

Comment: Была такая же проблема, но в другом контексте. Решение - сломались относительные пути (потому что они перемещали относительно корня проекта). Возможно в этом деле?

Comment: @mister_svinia, у меня вроде как все верно, путь в браузер передается как
`<img src="/media/book_covers/alves_tUd8z7n.jpg" alt="OSGi in Depth"`
Папка медиа находится в корне приложения на одном уровне с файлом **manage.py**

Comment: Если отдельно открывается, а в странице не открывается, то в момент загрузки страницы смотрите в мониторинге сети, куда какие запросы отправляет браузер для загрузки картинок и что ему на это отвечает веб-сервер